# Attempting to change velocity at screen edge not working

Tags: java, coordinates

The result should simply cause a bounce effect off the edge of the screen, but instead the object twitches left and right but doesn't move left the same as it does moving right...

This is the method to move the rectangle; (The input here is the same 'xVelocity' that is being changed in the if statement, it does this because there are multiple objects)

```
public void moveX (float x) {
    if(rectangle.right >= Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH || rectangle.left <= 0){
        xVelocity = -xVelocity;
    }
    rectangle.left += x;
    rectangle.right += x;
}
```

This method is just applied to different rectangles in an update method, they move to the right just fine but I'm not sure what the issue is with turning around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a `SCREEN_WIDTH` of 100, a `right` value of 95, and an `xVelocity` of 10.

Now call `moveX(xVelocity)`.

First, `xVelocity` is left unchanged, then `right` is incremented to 105.

Call `moveX(xVelocity)` again.

`xVelocity` is changed to -10, then `right` is incremented to 115, since the argument `x` is +10.

Call `moveX(xVelocity)` again.

`xVelocity` is changed back to +10, then `right` is decremented to 105, since the argument `x` is -10.

Now we are back to the same conditions as after the first call, so your block jitters back and forth at the screen edge.

---

To prevent this, you could use:

```
if(rectangle.right >= Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH) {
    xVelocity = -Math.abs(xVelocity);
} else if ( rectangle.left <= 0) {
    xVelocity = +Math.abs(xVelocity);
}
```